# How to attach pdf file represented as bytes(response from SOAP API) to an Opportunity?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soap-api, attachment, pdf

I have e response from a SOAP API which looks like the following

```
<GetReportResult>
        <Xml>
           <report xmlns=""/>
        </Xml>
        <Html/>
        <Files>
           <File>
               <Bytes>(pdf bytes are here)JVBERi0xLjcKJeTjz...</Bytes>
               <ContentType>application/pdf</ContentType>
               <FileName>PayNet Credit History Report - 
               113196132.pdf</FileName>
               <FileSize>41262</FileSize>
           </File>
        </Files>
        <ErrorCode>0</ErrorCode>
        <ErrorDescription/>
     </GetReportResult>
```

How can I save these bytes, which represent the pdf file, to a sObject? I know that attaching is done via Attachment object I successfully save plain text but the same code does not work for the pdf.

```
 public void AttachResponseToOpportunity(String xmlResponse, String contentType, String fileName, Id parentId, Boolean isPrivate) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

    Blob body = Blob.valueOf(xmlResponse);

    attachment.Body = body;
    attachment.Name = fileName;
    attachment.IsPrivate = isPrivate;
    attachment.ContentType = contentType;
    attachment.ParentId = parentId;

    List<SObject> attachments = new List<SObject> { attachment };
    UpsertSObjects(attachments);
}
```

I found a couple of articles that show how I can save a VF page as pdf but none of them helps me because I have the pdf in bytes, not as a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello after a bit more research I found out how to save the pdf bytes as an Attachment object.

This is the code:

```
 public void AttachResponseToOpportunity(String pdfBytes, String contentType, String fileName, Id parentId, Boolean isPrivate) {
    Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

    attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(pdfBytes);
    attachment.Name = fileName;
    attachment.IsPrivate = isPrivate;
    attachment.ContentType = contentType;
    attachment.ParentId = parentId;

    List<SObject> attachments = new List<SObject> { attachment };
    UpsertSObjects(attachments);
}
```